# Setting a field directly on the class definition in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, field

Is it a good practice to do this in ReactJS?

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<div></div>);
    },

    field: 'value', // is this safe?
    method: function () { 
        // do something with field
    }
})
```

Before starting to suggest that I should use `this.props` or `this.state`, for me it's not the case, because those are fields that do not affect rendering in any way directly, they just work together to control the rendering.

I would like to use the React class as I do with regular javascript 'classes'.

My main concern here is how those fields and methods are handled inside React, and if the fields are set on the instance itself or **directly on the prototype**, which would not be suitable at all for what I need.

I ran a quick test and it seems that the fields are set on the instance, and the methods on the prototype, which is ideal. But is this the expected and documented behavior? And is this safe for future versions?

Comment: Why not using getIinitialState ?

Comment: getInitialState sets the values on the state, but this is not suitable for me, as I've explained. Even if I used the state, when changing those fields that I need (and they are a lot, and they get changed a lot), I would have to use setState, which triggers a render, and it becomes very messy.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can work the way you are doing and that it's safe. However if I understand well you are proceeding data calculation/transformation directly in the view.
So I would advise that you remove this logic from the view and treat it in the model part of a mvc or mv*, in your backbone models, or in your flux store for example.

This way you won't be mixing data transformation logic and pure rendering.

Comment: Actually I use this component for a <video> wrapper, so there's no data calculation going on. There are just event handlers for the native events and logical fields for controlling the behavior of it.

Comment: but you wrote "and they are a lot, and they get changed a lot" so my point is that you should put them in some model and just setup the getters in your view, you manipulate your handlermodel instead you doing that in your view, also it will make things more reusable (your handler model can be used for another different video view for example).

Comment: Yes, this is also an option, and I already have the code which is setup in this way, because I didn't use React from the start, and I could just link it to the React methods. The thing is that I expect that the code will be lighter and easier to read with all the logic in the React class.

Comment: I think modularity and reusability is the best option and that it'll make things more readable and maintainable in fact but it's just my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I would say so, I have been using things like this for a while and have not seen any issues. For example, let's say you want a handler of some sort that you want to pass to nested components, you would create the function in this component and pass it as a prop to a child. I believe they have examples that use similar concept in the ReactJS Facebook site.

Comment: Great, but have you used fields that store data and not methods? Because from what you say I understand that you have only used methods (e.g. handlers in your case), but those aren't problematic regardless of the scenario. But for a field that stores data it makes a great difference if you set in on the prototype versus the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood React is just looping through the properties of the object you pass to `createClass` and copying them to the prototype of the Component. Primitive values like strings or numbers obviously cannot be copied by reference, so don't get shared across all instances, whereas objects, functions, arrays and so on will.

If you want to work with values that are just local to the component instance you need to use the state API. I'm not sure what you mean by "[state and props] do not affect rendering in any way directly, they just work together to control the rendering". The whole point of props and state is that they work together to generate values to be used when (re)rendering.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

A React component should only render in response to either changing props or changing state. You cannot/shouldn't trigger a re-render by mutating other fields directly.

You need to think of your component as something closer to a pure function. State and props go in at the top, and static VDOM/HTML comes out.

I would re-write your example as,

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {field: 'value'};
  },
  render: function () {
    var field = this.state.field;
    return (<div>{field}</div>);
  },
  method: function () { 
    var field = this.state.field;
    // do something with field
    this.setState({field: 'anotherValue'});
  }
})
```